# How to enable/disable a certain textbox depending on which radiobutton was checked?

Tags: jquery

I've 3 radiobuttons and a textbox next to each other (also 3 text boxes) like this:

```
<input type = "radio" id = "myRadio" value = "A" checked = "checked"/>
<input type = "text" id = "myText1"/> <br/>

<input type = "radio" id = "myRadio" value = "B" />
<input type = "text" id = "myText2"/><br/>

<input type = "radio" id = "myRadio" value = "C" />
<input type = "text" id = "myText2"/>
```

The first radioButton is **checked** by default, and the textbox next to it should be **enabled**. the 2 other radiobuttons are **not checked**, and the textbox next to them should be **disabled**.

I need a Jquery script so that:

1. when a radiobutton is checked, the textbox next to it should be enabled
2. the textboxes next to the radiobutton unchecked remain disabled

In other words, only the textbox next to a radiobutton that's checked is enabled.

**Personally, I have difficult writing the script because all the radiobutton have the same id.**

I've tried this, but I'm getting all 2 radiobuttons checked at the same time while only the first textbox remains enabled.

```
$(":text").attr("disabled", "disabled");
if($(":radio").attr("checked"))
{
  $(":radio:checked + :text").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
};
```

**EDIT**

Look at the code above. When the page loads for the first time, the first radiobutton (whose **value = "A"**) is checked, so the textbox next to it (whose **id = "myText1"**) should be enabled. When user clicks a different radiobutton, for instance the one with a **value = "B"**, the textbox next to it (whose **id = "myText2"**) should be enabled, and so on.

I hope I have been more explicit this time.

By the way, I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why do they all have the same id? To group them? You could asign them the same **name** instead of the id then this problem would be very simple.

Comment: Are there any special reason why the radiobuttons have the same id?
And is the value of the radiobuttons important?

Comment: @matschie: because they are generated by a loop <% foreach(var item in the Model)%>

Comment: @Falle: yes, because, as the id and name are the same (generated by the loop), only the value distinguish them. I'm in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Can you add a counter to the loop, give them unique IDs with the same name? Control ids should always be unique. Names don't need to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need a plug-in for this.  Adapting from James' code, the following should work (and will correctly disable boxes on load):

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
       {
           if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               $('input[type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
           }
       });

    $('input[type=radio]:first').attr('checked', 'checked').change();
});
```

Comment: It working, but only when I start clicking button. So, can you take into account the fact that, when the page loads for the first time or reloaded for editing, the 3 textboxes are enabled. So the code you've just given needs to take into account the initial state of the radiobutton as well.

Comment: @Richard77 - I've added a few lines to take into account the initial state.

Comment: I had to edit the last line to get what I wanted. Thanks a lot. See my answer a the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='radio']).checked(function()
   {
       $("input[type='text']").disable();
       $(this).next().enabled();
   });
```

This will require a plugin which handles enable/disable (which for some odd reason is not in the core jQuery libray), of which [there](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/2258) [are](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-disableenable-element-with.html) [many](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/disabler) and easy to google.

Comment: @Sorry for the stupid question I've to ask you. How do I use the plugin? I've got to the page. But, when I click download, I'm not getting a download file manager, rather a page with the code. Should I create a js file and copy/paste the code?

Comment: @Richard: yep, that will do it.

Comment: currant: again, I'll need to put a link to that on my page? (another dumb question from me)

Comment: @Richard: Yes.  `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.pluginnamehere.js"> </script>`  (oddly, it can't be a self-closing tag.  It must be an open & a close)

Comment: t: I did what you advised, but nothing happened. I think I didn't express myself well. check out the EDIt of the post above.

Answer (score 1):

```
Enabling and disabling sections/div's based on Selection.
/**Sample function to disable and enable sections**/
function onChnageFunction(strSelect) {
if( strSelect == "CP")
{
$('#field1Name').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#field2Name').removeAttr('disabled');
}
else
{
//Defaulting before disabling
$('#field1Name').val("0");
$('#field2Name').val("0");
$('#field1Name').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#field2Name').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
}

/*On change attachment*/
$(document).on('change', '[name="selectComponentname"]', function () {
var strSelect = $(this).val();
/*calling helper for logic implementation*/
onChnageFunction(strSelect);
});

/*On load attachment*/
$(document).ready(function() {
var strSelect = $("#selectComponentname").val();
//calling helper for logic implementation
onChnageFunction(strSelect);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ender,

I edited the last 2 lines of the code you provided and evrything is working now as I wanted.

```
$('input[type=text]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('input[type=radio]:checked').next().removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
```

The last line takes into account the primary initial state of the radiobutton then enables accordingly the textbox next to it.

Thanks a lot.